# Bad URL Parameters in concated links

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I used for example

```
 Set @FT1TARGETLINK = Concat('https://www.domain.com/',@LANGUAGEURL,@COUNTRYURL,@FT1LINK,'?
utm_source=',@CCLOWER2,@GASOURCE,'&utm_medium=',@GAMEDIUM,'&utm_campaign=',@GACAMPAIGN)
```

in my email and have placed `%%=RedirectTo(@FT1TARGETLINK)=%%` in my `<a href` ...

When clicking the links in the sent email it transfers bad parameters, that are not in use in this specific email.

https://www.domain.com/de-de/category/?utm_source=de-newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=sparbuchweek4-cw37-1-20170912&@LANGUAGEURL,@COUNTRYURL,%27cart/%27,@basketid,%27&utm_source=%27,@LANGUAGECODE,%27-%27,@SCOUNTRYCODE,%27%27,%2720170912

> Bad Parameters:
>   20170912&@LANGUAGEURL,@COUNTRYURL,%27cart/%27,@basketid,%27&utm_source=%27,@LANGUAGECODE,%27-%27,@SCOUNTRYCODE,%27%27,%2720170912

What could be the reason for that?

Thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

Try using the TreatAsContent function before redirect.

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(TreatAsContent(Concat(view_email_url,"&ep=20110902&oeid=20110902",Substring(Uppercase(Source),1,1))))=%%">
```

If this does not work, then try accessing all the variables like this 
v(@LANGUAGEURL), instead of just @LANGUAGEURL inside the concat function